# Data corruption - ERROR: could not open segment 2 of relation

Tags: postgresql

I am getting the below error for production database. I am new to PostgreSQL database. I need help to get the below error fixed.

```
2015-10-28 10:25:04,154 [monitor-thread-pool1-thread-6] ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: could not open segment 2 of relation 1663/98913/98947 (target block 427542): No such file or
directory



server1=>  select oid::regclass from pg_class where relfilenode =98947;
          oid

 alert_instance_history
(1 row)


server1=>  select oid::regclass from pg_class where relfilenode =98913;
 oid

(0 rows)

server1=> select * from pg_database where oid=1663;
 datname | datdba | encoding | datistemplate | datallowconn | datconnlimit | datlastsysoid | datvacuumxid | datfrozenxid | dattablespace | datconfig | datacl
---------+--------+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------
(0 rows)

1. server1=> select version();
                                          version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.1.4 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.3.5 (Debian 1:3.3.5-13)
(1 row)
```

Q1. Error says 2 relations but I can only find 98947, how i can check the other segment ?
Q2. I did just select on this table alert_instance_history, I can see records from this table. Do I need to check any thing else ?

```
server1=> select min(eventtimestamp) from alert_instance_history;
```

> WARNING:  could not write block 427542 of 1663/98913/98947 DETAIL: 
>   Multiple failures --- write error may be permanent. ERROR:  could not
>   open segment 2 of relation 1663/98913/98947 (target block 427542): No
>   such file or directory CONTEXT:  writing block 427542 of relation
>   1663/98913/98947 server1=> server1=> reindex table
>   alert_instance_history; WARNING:  could not write block 427542 of
>   1663/98913/98947 DETAIL:  Multiple failures --- write error may be
>   permanent. ERROR:  could not open segment 2 of relation
>   1663/98913/98947 (target block 427542): No such file or directory
>   CONTEXT:  writing block 427542 of relation 1663/98913/98947

Q3. What's the posible option have to restore, Can I restore just one table ? 
Backup of this database is done using `pg_dump` utility.

Comment: I checked some other random tables. I see the same error :
Server1=> select min(CREATEDATE) from alertinstance;
WARNING:  could not write block 427542 of 1663/98913/98947
DETAIL:  Multiple failures --- write error may be permanent.
ERROR:  could not open segment 2 of relation 1663/98913/98947 (target block 427542): No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  writing block 427542 of relation 1663/98913/98947

Comment: I suggest moving this to http://dba.stackexchange.com/  StackOverflow is more about programming quesitons.   That said, this sounds like you might be having hardware (disk) failure. Inspect the server syslog to help confirm/deny and get your system admins involved if relevant.  My first concern would be to ascertain whether you indeed have imminent disk failure (or other hardware problems) or not. If you do then restoring data to a failing disk is the last thing you should want to do.

Comment: X-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/119466/7788 .